# permitindo acesso ao webserver apenas com android

Tags: html, apache

Galera tenho uma pasta no meu site chamada webserver, dentro dela tenho vários arquivos php que montam o `json` que é enviado ao meu app que estou montando. Porém eu queria bloquear essa pasta para não ser acessado por nenhum navegador, apenas pelo android. Isso e possível de ser feito via `htacess`?

Hoje eu configurei o meu htacess para não listar nenhum arquivo dentro da pasta, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

Para deteção do android, usando htaccess tente:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /android/$1 [L,QSA] # redirect aqui

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipod|ipad|windows" [NC] # redirecao para os outros
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://YOU_SHALL_NOT_PASS/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Mas disse que tinha uns ficheiros php. Eu aproveitava isso, e colocava um primeiro ficheiro com isso, este ficheiro seria o primeiro a ser lido pelo servidor:

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$devicesAllowed = array('android' => 'http://www.android.com'); // aqui colocamos os 'aparelhos' admitidos, neste caso é só android com os respetivos url para redireção
foreach($devicesAllowed as $device => $url) {
    if(strpos($useragent, $device) !== false) {
        header('Location:' .$url);
    }
}
header('Location: YOU SHALL NOT PASS'); // redireção para os outros clientes (ios, desktop etc...)
```

Note que do lado cliente nós podemos falsear isso, existem até *plugins/add-ons* para navegadores para fazer isso. Não conte como sendo viável a 100%